# Google Analytics reports API - Insufficient Permission 403

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-analytics-api, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access data from google-analytics. I am following the guide and is able to gauthorize my user and get the code from oauth.

When I try to access data from GA I only get 403 Insufficient Permission back. Do I somehow have to connect my project in Google API console to my analytics project? How would I do this? Or is there some other reason why I get 403 Insufficient Permission back?

I am doing this in Python with Django and I have Analytics API turned on i my API console!

Comment: put google-analytics java-script and mention template place as well?

Comment: what do you mean? I am using the exact code from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

Comment: It should be getting everything it needs from client_secrets.json file.

Comment: This also happens when you do not declare some of the scopes, that you endup using in you code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had the same problem, but now is solved.
Use View ID Not account ID, the 'View ID', can be found in the Admin->Profiles->Profile Settings tab

UPDATE
now, if you have more a account , you must go:   Admin -> Select account -> under View-> click on View Settings

Comment: New way is: Admin -> Select Site -> Under "View" -> View Settings

Comment: I tried it with both ga:XXXXXXX and XXXXXXX... They don't seem to work :(



`$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:XXXXXXX", "2015-08-20", "2015-08-31", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );`
`$data = $service->data_ga->get("XXXXXXX", "2015-08-20", "2015-08-31", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; sounds as simple as adding the email concerned to the list of users having at least a read access to your google analytics account
[Some complete (but not up-to-date, rails code speaking) tutorial here](http://www.slatestudio.com/blog/p/how-to-pull-google-analytics-data-from-rails-app)

Should we mentions the scopes too ? googleapis.com/auth/analytics and googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly I guess would be sufficient

and yep, the above question (view id instead of account id, as usually used in the tracking) is something to set as explained.

With those 3 checks, you're about to make it work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You  should use View ID Not account ID, the 'View ID', you can go:

Admin -> Select Site -> Under "View" -> View Settings , if it doesn't works

you can go: Admin->Profiles->Profile Settings

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the email address you got from the API to the Google Analytics property. After that you should add the View ID.